# How to solve this first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So D.E. are pretty new to me but I have made some linear ones.
However, I can't seem to get how to solve a non-linear one.
$$
(2x+3y+4){\rm d}x + (3x+4y+5){\rm d}y = 0
$$

Comment: Hint: 3ydx+3xdy=d(3xy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution goes as follows:

$$(2x+3y+4)dx+(3x+4y+5)dy=0$$
$$(2x+4) dx + (4y+5) dy + 3(xdy+ydx) = 0 $$
$$(2x+4) dx + (4y+5) dy + 3d(xy) = 0 $$
Integrating both sides, we get
$$x^2+4x+2y^2+5y+3xy=c$$

Which is the required solution.

Comment: Thanks, but what if 3ydx and 3xdy didn't have the same coefficients?

Comment: @Juembles then you have to use the method for homogeneous equations like Harish's answer. That is, you have to make the substitution $y=vx$.

Comment: ok thanks i get it now

Comment: @Juembles If my answer proved helpful, then you can accept it by clicking the tick on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, introduce new variables $X$ & $Y$,

let $x=X+1$ & $y=Y-2$ $$(2x+3y+4)\ dx+(3x+4y+5)\ dy$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+3y+4}{3x+4y+5}$$
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=-\frac{2X+3Y}{3X+4Y}=-\frac{2+3\frac{Y}{X}}{3+4\frac{Y}{X}}$$
let $Y=VX\implies \frac{dY}{dX}=V+X\frac{dV}{dX}$
$$V+X\frac{dV}{dX}=-\frac{2+3V}{3+4V}$$
$$X\frac{dV}{dX}=-\frac{4V^2+6V+2}{3+4V}$$
$$\int \frac{(3+4V)\ dV}{4V^2+6V+2}=-\int \frac{dX}{X}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d(2V^2+3V+1)}{2V^2+3V+1}=-\int \frac{dX}{X}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln|2V^2+3V+1|=-\ln|X|+\ln C$$

I hope you can take it from here

Answer (score 0):

HINTS: for the general form of ODE $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{ax+by+c}{px+qy+r}$$ always let $x=X+h$ & $y=Y+k$
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{aX+bY+(ah+bk+c)}{pX+qY+(ph+qk+r)}$$
setting $ah+by+c=0$ & $ph+qk+r=0$, solve for $h$ & $k$ to reduce the ODE into homogeneous equation as follows $$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{aX+bY}{pX+qY}$$ 
which can be easily solved

Answer (score 0):

## Hint:

the type of this D.E is exact differential equation
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=3$$